# getting the length of a list with several lists (with dictionary items) within it

Tags: python

I have a "list" (emphasis on the quotes) of a list of dictionary items that I am trying to get the length of. The current format (JSON-like) of the item looks like this:

```
x = {"fullgame":"+2","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":"-1"}
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}
{"fullgame":"-2","firsthalf":"-0.5","secondhalf":""}
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"-0.5","secondhalf":""}
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}
```

Obviously, the length of this list would be 6 if it were formatted correctly. I have been attempting to split the items at the closing bracket or using append, but I always end up getting a printout of the length of each item (or worse). Essentially, I guess I am really just trying to turn the above object into what is printed below because I know it gets the output I am looking for...

```
x = [{"fullgame":"+2","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":"-1"},
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""},
{"fullgame":"-2","firsthalf":"-0.5","secondhalf":""},
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""},
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"-0.5","secondhalf":""},
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""},]
```

Forgive the newbie question. I have been searching for answers to this, but have come up empty though I am sure it is pretty simple.

**EDIT: I am just trying to get the length of this list which is much, much longer than above 6 entries. After that I will be looping through that list skipping every 7 entries and pulling specific values and pushing them into a csv. I have had no problems with that portion of the project though**

Comment: can you just split on `"\n"`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you really want to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If your x is like this here a try :

```
x = '{"fullgame":"+2","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":"-1"}\
     {"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}\
     {"fullgame":"-2","firsthalf":"-0.5","secondhalf":""}\
     {"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}\
     {"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"-0.5","secondhalf":""}\
     {"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}'

import ast
import re

text = re.sub(r'(})', r'\1,', x)
result = ast.literal_eval(text)
print(list(result))
```

It will o/p like :

```
[{'secondhalf': '-1', 'fullgame': '+2', 'firsthalf': 'Ev'}, 
 {'secondhalf': '', 'fullgame': '-1.5', 'firsthalf': 'Ev'}, 
 {'secondhalf': '', 'fullgame': '-2', 'firsthalf': '-0.5'}, 
 {'secondhalf': '', 'fullgame': '-1.5', 'firsthalf': 'Ev'}, 
 {'secondhalf': '', 'fullgame': '-1.5', 'firsthalf': '-0.5'},    
 {'secondhalf': '', 'fullgame': '-1.5', 'firsthalf': 'Ev'}]
```

Then you can easly find the length of the list like `print(len(list(result)))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 'x' as a string, you can do this:

```
x = x.replace("}{","}!!@${")
l = x.split("!!@$") # Add some dummy delimiter
print(len(l))
print(l[0])
```

> 6
>
> {"fullgame":"+2","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":"-1"}

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the count of each dict in the string...

```
x = """{"fullgame":"+2","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":"-1"}
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}
{"fullgame":"-2","firsthalf":"-0.5","secondhalf":""}
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"-0.5","secondhalf":""}
{"fullgame":"-1.5","firsthalf":"Ev","secondhalf":""}"""

print(x.count("}\n{")+1)
```

**Output:**

```
6
```